# What are the limitations of the demo?

Tags: torchlight-2

I have noticed that there is now a Torchlight 2 demo available for download on Steam, which I am currently in the process of downloading. However, I've had a quick look around and can't seem to find what the limitations of the demo are in comparison to the full game.

- Is there a maximum time limit to how long you can play?
- Is the limitation on content? How far through the game can I play in the demo?
- Can I join multiplayer games with the demo?
- Can I proceed in the full game from the spot I left at the end of the demo?

Is there anything else I should know about the demo?

Comment: it should be trivial to ask, whether there is a limitation on content. Eventually, it is a demonstration of what you WOULD get if you bought the game with the complete content.

Comment: It is worth noting that if you get the demo on Steam, and then subsequently purchase the full game on Steam, the demo gets upgraded and very little data is downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all the character customization options are available -- at least that's how it appeared to me as I booted up the demo for the first time last night.  There's also a randomization feature if you just want to click that until you get something you like.

I also like the fact that each class can be male or female and that when sending your pet to town you can also include a limited shopping list that he'll fill (potions and identify and town portal scrolls).

I believe the demo is so large because it includes the entire game but, of course, it's locked beyond the demo part until you pay for it.

Oh, one other addition/change from the first game -- you may now "fish" with dynamite.  Not very sporting, but faster -- though I think the instructions for using dynamite to fish say you won't be able to catch as many fish from a given fishing hole as you can with a fishing pole.

Comment: -1 doesn't mention multiplayer, quite an important limitation (although not to the op, apparently. But the answer has to be useful to everyone)

Answer (score 7):

Multiplayer mode is disabled in the demo from Steam, both LAN and online.

All of the character classes appear to be available, although I am unsure if all of the customisation options (hair style, face style, hair colour) are available in the demo.

Gameplay seems to be unhindered until the 'Trail of the Grand Regent' quest;

[image: Trail of the Grand Regent]

Trying to proceed forward to Crows Pass presents you with a 'thank you for playing' screen;

[image: Thank you for playing!]